# Uploading files and storing them into a folder?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to program my application to upload images and then store them in a folder. It prints out the details of the file but doesn't store it into the folder. I am following the User Guide and answers on here and I still don't know what I am doing wrong?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class UploadAvatarCommand implements Command {

    @Override
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        String contextRoot = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        factory.setRepository(new File(contextRoot + "WEB-INF/tmp"));
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            for (FileItem item : items) {
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    // Process form file field (input type="file").
                    System.out.println("Field name: " + item.getFieldName());
                    System.out.println("File name: " + item.getName());
                    System.out.println("File size: " + item.getSize());
                    System.out.println("File type: " + item.getContentType());

                    String fileName = item.getName();
                    try {
                        File saveFile = new File(fileName);
                        saveFile.createNewFile();
                        item.write(saveFile);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            try {
                throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
            } catch (ServletException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return "profile";
    }

}
```

Comment: You should print out fileName  and saveFile.getPath() on your console. Where are you looking for the file ?

Comment: You get some exception? Can you send us how do you upload the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any error then this piece of code:

```
File saveFile = new File(fileName);
saveFile.createNewFile();
item.write(saveFile);
```

creates a new file with the name `fileName` (that is only a simple name like "file.txt") in the current folder.

If you want to know which is your current workfolder try to print this:

```
System.out.println("Current folder: " + (new File(".")).getCanonicalPath())
```

so you can check if the files are here.

Then if you want to put files on the folder that you desire you can use:

```
File saveFile = new File("/my/upload/folder",fileName);
```

and replace "/my/upload/folder" with the path of the folder you prefer.

Comment: `new File(".")).getCanonicalPath()` shows my Eclipse root folder. Is there a way to get it to store images into my project folder in my workspace (which is not in my Eclipse folder)?

Comment: Look where I write "_then if you want to put files on..._" I explain you how to do it.

Comment: Yeah I got that. This works: `new File("../Workspace/Project2/My_Application/WebContent/images/" + fileName);` but isn't there a better way that's more maintainable for when I move the application to a production server?

Comment: You can use this method to get a path within your application folder: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String) search getRealPath.

Answer (score 0):

This programs work fine.

this variable go on the top

```
  private static final String DATA_DIRECTORY = "data";
```

this is the  main programs

```
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    String contextRoot = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

    factory.setRepository(new File(contextRoot));
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    try {
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                // Process form file field (input type="file").
                System.out.println("Field name: " + item.getFieldName());
                System.out.println("File name: " + item.getName());
                System.out.println("File size: " + item.getSize());
                System.out.println("File type: " + item.getContentType());

                String fileName = item.getName();
                try {
                    String uploadFolder = getServletContext().getRealPath("")+ File.separator + DATA_DIRECTORY;
                    String filePath = uploadFolder + File.separator + fileName;
                    File saveFile = new File(filePath);                        
                    saveFile.createNewFile();
                    item.write(saveFile);                        

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        try {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
        } catch (ServletException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```